# How to add UIVibrancyEffect to an existing UILabel ( IBOutlet )?

Tags: swift, ios8, uiblureffect, uivibrancyeffect

I have a working ViewController with working UIBlurEffect. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.frame = self.view.frame
        blurView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.view.insertSubview(blurView, atIndex: 0)
}
```

Now I would like to add a UIVibranyEffect to the nameLabel.
How to add UIVibrancyEffect programatically to an existing UILabel?

Answer (score 9):

You need to instantiate an UIVisualEffectView and add whatever you want to be vibrant inside it. For example:

```
    // Blur Effect
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)

    // Vibrancy Effect
    let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect)
    let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)
    vibrancyEffectView.frame = view.bounds

    // Label for vibrant text
    let vibrantLabel = UILabel()
    vibrantLabel.text = "Vibrant"

    // Add label to the vibrancy view
    vibrancyEffectView.contentView.addSubview(vibrantLabel)

    // Add the vibrancy view to the blur view
    blurEffectView.contentView.addSubview(vibrancyEffectView)
```