# How can I make a UILabel's text style adapt to the blurred background in tvOS?

Tags: swift, uilabel, tvos, uivibrancyeffect

I want to create a `UILabel` that adapts to the blurred background of a tvOS application, like on this image from a system function. Note how the text looks brownish and how it blends in with the background - I want to achieve the same effect. Is it possible to do with a public API?

[image: Text with adapted design in tvOS]

Comment: that's the effect of UIVisualEffectView

Comment: @zombie Thank you, this was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable with two nested `UIVisualEffectView`s. You should apply a `UIBlurEffect` to the parent and add a `UIVibrancyEffect` to the child. It pretty much works in the same way as it does on iOS.

You can achieve this in Interface Builder by using **Visual Effect Views with Blur and Vibrancy**, which creates the following view structure:

[image: Visual Effect Views with Blur and Vibrancy - view structure]

You can also create this effect programmatically with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845142/3151675).